# Does a motherboard have to support 64-bit or is it just the CPU?

Tags: 64-bit, cpu, motherboard

Do I need to have both components to support 64-bit, motherboard and CPU.  Or is it just the CPU that matters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To quote [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457053.aspx) (eh),

> Windows XP 64-bit Edition requires a 64-bit motherboard and chip set,
>   available through Intel and several OEMs.

In general, it helps to understand how a [64-bit system differs](http://www.atomicmpc.com.au/Feature/141236,64-bit-computing.aspx) from the 32-bit one.

The first couple of pages from this old article are also a good read,
[64-bit computing in theory and practice AMD and Intel make the leap to 64 bits](http://techreport.com/articles.x/8131/1)

Comment: the second link is not working..

Answer (score 0):

A motherboard usually supports some kind of CPUs and may not support some other kind. So, if a motherboard supports X CPU which happens to be 64-bit then it is supported, but that doesn't mean that it will support Y CPU which is 32-bit.

It really drills down to what models of cpus a motherboard supports regardless of 32-bit or 64-bit. Check the motherboard's manual to know which CPUs are fully supported.