# 32bit vs 64bit is a property of CPU, motherboard or both?

Tags: 64-bit, cpu, motherboard, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a motherboard have to support 64-bit or is it just the CPU?](https://superuser.com/questions/59623/does-a-motherboard-have-to-support-64-bit-or-is-it-just-the-cpu)

1. For computer, being 32/64bit is a property of CPU, motherboard, or both?
2. How do I recognize that "computer" is 32 or 64 bit? I only recongize it by looking if the Windows provided with it are 32 or 64 bit... but that's not ideal.

Comment: @techie007, nope, question you cited is one step further - my question is more basic, more general

Comment: It's also a good idea to restrict a question to just one question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a property of both the motherboard and the CPU collectively. A processor can be either 32-bit or have 64-bit extensions, but it needs a compatible motherboard to plug into. A motherboard could support 64-bit processors, but you could also plug a 32-bit one into it if you didn't need/want/afford 64-bit capability.

For question #2, there are several ways to determine whether the processor is operating in 32-bit or 64-bit mode. As others have commented though, this has been answered elsewhere.

Comment: thanks, so can we say that I can't plug 64-bit CPU into 32-bit only motherboard?

Comment: That's correct. The 32-bit motherboard would likely have been from an older product line, so it wouldn't support newer CPU families that are 64-bit capable. I suppose it's possible for a company to deliberately segment the market by selling 32-bit-only motherboards for cheaper, but pretty much all modern motherboards and processors are 64-bit capable.

Comment: Thanks. Well, now I have 2 answers that seem to state completely the opposite, so I'm not really sure which one is correct.

Answer (score 5):

CPU determines this.  However, you can install a 32bit OS on a 64bit processor

Comment: And NOT vice versa.  If you're running a 64-bit OS, you have to be on a 64-bit capable processor.

Comment: Thanks Dave. What do you mean by *"CPU determines this"*? Do you mean that motherboard doesn't have property of being 32/64 bit? Contrary to what I'd expect (the bus is on the MB also, isn't it?)

Comment: The CPU, not the bus does the code interpreting.

Comment: "Do you mean that motherboard doesn't have property of being 32/64 bit?" - Yes, just CPU.

Comment: @RichardHolloway, I thought that the 4MB RAM limitation is because some address limitations, which are present on the bus.... aren't they?

Comment: Ah the 3GB problem! Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier and the section "Chipset and other motherboard issues"

Comment: @RichardHolloway, no no, please don't focus on RAM, I'm just asking: are you sure there is no bottleneck in the motherboard, that would disable the 64-bit CPU functionality?